# Altitude of a right simplex (high-dimensional generalization of a right triangle)

Tags: geometry, triangles, simplex

Assume that I have a right triangle, where the right angle is centered at the origin, and the two sides go in the $x$ and $y$ directions.  I can calculate the [altitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_(triangle)) of the triangle using the following formula:

$f = \frac{ab}{c} = \frac{ab}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$

Where $a$ and $b$ are the lengths of the sides of the triangle.  $c$ is the length of the hypotenuse.  $f$ is the length of the altitude.

The formula is obtained from **[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right_triangle#Altitudes)**

---

Assume that I generalize this right triangle to higher dimensions.  In 3-dimensions, this would be a tetrahedron with one vertex at the origin.  3 edges of the tetrahedron would lie on the $x$-axis, $y$-axis, and $z$-axis respectively.  In higher dimensions, the pattern would stay the same.

In $n$-dimensions, I would like to find the generalization to altitude, which in 3-dimensions would be the length from the origin to the closest point on the face opposite the vertex.  In $n$-dimensions it is difficult to explain the shape that is created.

**Is the formula simply the following?  Or how would one derive the formula?**

$f = \frac{\prod_{i=0}^{n}{l_i}}{\sqrt{\sum_{i=0}^n{l_i^2}}}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll write $a_i$ rather than $l_i$ for the edge of the simplex along the $i$th axis, since I find that less confusing to read.

We're looking for the distance from the origin to the hyperplane $H$ that passes through the $n$ vertices $(a_1,0,\ldots,0),$  $(0,a_2,0,\ldots,0),$
 $(0,0,a_3,0,\ldots,0),$ and so forth up to  $(0,\ldots,0,a_n).$
That hyperplane has equation
$$
\frac{x_1}{a_1} + \frac{x_2}{a_2} + \frac{x_3}{a_3} + \cdots
 + \frac{x_n}{a_n} = 1.
$$

This can also be written as an inner product of vectors:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac1{a_1}& \frac1{a_2}& \frac1{a_3}& \cdots& \frac1{a_n}
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} x_1& x_2& x_3& \cdots& x_n \end{bmatrix}^T = 1,
$$
which tells us that the vector
$\newcommand{v}{\mathbf v}\v = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac1{a_1}& \frac1{a_2}& \frac1{a_3}& \cdots& \frac1{a_n}
\end{bmatrix}$
is orthogonal to hyperplane $H$ and is therefore parallel
to the altitude.

Let $k\v$ be the vector from the origin to the nearest point on the hyperplane $H.$ Then its inner product with $\v$ is 
$\v (k\v)^T = 1.$
This implies that $k \|\v\|^2 = k(\v\v^T) = 1$ as well, so
$$
k = \frac1{\| \v \|^2} 
= \frac{1}{\frac1{a_1^2} + \frac1{a_2^2} + \frac1{a_3^2} + \cdots
   + \frac1{a_n^2}}
$$
But then 
$$
f = \|k\v\| = k\|\v\| = \frac1{\|\v\|}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac1{a_1^2} + \frac1{a_2^2} + \frac1{a_3^2} + \cdots
   + \frac1{a_n^2}}}
$$
is the distance from the origin to the hyperplane $H.$

Let's check this for the case $n=2.$ If $n=2$ then
$$
f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac1{a_1^2} + \frac1{a_2^2}}}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{a_1^2 + a_2^2}{a_1^2 a_2^2}}}
= \frac{a_1 a_2}{\sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2}},
$$
which agrees with the two-dimensional formula.

For $n=3,$ however, we have
$$
f = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac1{a_1^2} + \frac1{a_2^2} + \frac1{a_3^2}}}
= \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{a_1^2 a_2^2 + a_1^2 a_3^2 + a_2^2 a_3^2}
              {a_1^2 a_2^2 a_3^2}}}
= \frac{a_1 a_2 a_3}{\sqrt{a_1^2 a_2^2 + a_1^2 a_3^2 + a_2^2 a_3^2}},
$$
whose numerator matches the proposed formula,
$$
\frac{\displaystyle\prod_{i=0}^n a_i}
     {\sqrt{\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n a_i^2}},
$$
but whose denominator does not match that formula.
The altitude could be written as follows:

$$
f = \frac{\displaystyle\prod_{i=0}^n a_i}
 {\sqrt{\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n \displaystyle\prod_{j\neq i} a_j^2}}.
$$

But I think it's simpler to write

$$
f = \frac{1}
 {\sqrt{\displaystyle\sum_{i=0}^n \frac1{a_i^2}}}.
$$

Comment: This is cool, because the answer is $\frac{1}{f^2} = \sum_{i=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{a_i^2}}$ which is a simple formula